# Real-time feed difference between actively refreshing and requiring reload

Tags: php, user-interface, real-time, tornado

On Facebook, the refreshing on the News Feed occurs in real-time. On other sites like LinkedIn or Twitter, it requires the user to click something like "Show 3 new updates".

I was wondering if there is actually a major difference in the two approaches from the back-end perspective, or is this mainly a UI consideration?

If it is a difference in back-end, what are the differences?

Comment: Should be asked on ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just UI considerations, if Twitter can get the number of updates, it can probably get also the content of these updates.